# Use of Maybe in RTK Query GraphQL generated types

Tags: typescript, graphql, rtk-query

I have a TS problem that I'm trying to figure out, and I'm looking through various places where people are doing somewhat similar things. So I'm looking at the generated types for the [RTK Query generated GraphQl example code](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/blob/30ecd11aa0deb35dbbcec0a9749d3f438082764b/examples/query/react/graphql-codegen/src/app/services/types.generated.ts), and I see

`export type Maybe<T> = T;`

What is the advantage of using this over just using T?

TIA!

Comment: It should be `type Maybe<T> = T | undefined;`...? Something's off with your codegen.

Comment: It's not my codegen. I've edited the question to include the place I saw it. I feel fairly confident these guys know what they're doing, so I'm not willing to decide yet they don't.

Comment: Last time I used codegen I had `type Maybe<T> = T | undefined`. That was the point of `Maybe`: to make things optional. Maybe they have an option to disable that?

Comment: It depends on your Graphql schema. `SomeType` in gql translates to `Maybe<SomeType>` in TS - `SomeType!` in gql translates to `SomeType`. Everything in graphql is nullable by default.

Comment: @phry Can you comment on the specific schema used in the code I lined to?

Comment: @AmyBlankenship I would probably rather have to comment on the underlying graphql schema. My point is that in graphql, everything is nullable unless you add a `!` after. And the TS types have to reflect the graphql schema.

Comment: It seems like the generated code would result in types that are not nullable though?